# Could not load file or assembly 'ActiveUp.Net.Common.dll' or One of its dependencies. Operation is not supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, imacros

This is the Full error i have:

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Order Capture 2.0 \Order Capture2.0\bin\Release\ActiveUp.Net.Common.dll' or One of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515

I've Tried:

1. Clean up Solution. - Not Working.
2. Remove ActiveUp.Net.Common.dll Reference and Add New One. - Not Working.
3. Remove File in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

   - Not Working.
4. Download MailSystem.Net unzip and copy ActiveUp.Net.Common.dll paste to 
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ hoping it may work -Not Working.
5. Try Renew Webservice Reference Url since it's Connected to a Xamp php passing data's

   - Not Working.

what are the other possible things i could do to fix this problem..?

Comment: could this be the case? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80131515.aspx  -- unblock the zip file, unzip and try again

Comment: wow thanks very much sir... your the man! how can i check you?

Comment: I posted this as an answer, you're welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**unblock** the zip file, unzip again

reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80131515.aspx